# PHP mail form text boxes uneditable due to ...CSS?

Tags: php, html, css, forms

I've never had this problem before but I'm hoping someone else has. I have a php mail script that will not work on my page. It won't even let you type text into the text boxes. One of the options is a choice and you can't even make the dropdown work.The entire thing is totally uneditable.

I can take the same exact code and put it in a bare bones HTML file and it all works just find. Sends mail correctly, everything just as it should.

So evidently there is something either on my webpage or in my CSS file that is totally killing the HTML form, rendering it useless.

Here is the form code:

```
<form action="contact.php" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Your Name:</b></td>
            <td> <input type="text" name="yourname" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Subject:</b> </td>
            <td><select name="subject" />
                <option value=""> -- Please select -- </option>
                <option>Prayer Requests</option>
                <option>Praise Report</option>
                <option>General Feedback</option>
            </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>E-mail:</b> </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="email" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Your comments:</b></td>
            <td><textarea name="comments" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea><td></tr></td>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Send it!"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Here is the php script:

```
<?php
/* Set e-mail recipient */
$myemail  = "feedback@the-ecclesia.org";

/* Check all form inputs using check_input function */
$yourname = check_input($_POST['yourname'], "Enter your name");
$subject  = check_input($_POST['subject'], "Write a subject");
$email    = check_input($_POST['email']);
$website  = check_input($_POST['website']);
$likeit   = check_input($_POST['likeit']);
$comments = check_input($_POST['comments'], "Write your comments");

/* If e-mail is not valid show error message */
if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
{
    show_error("E-mail address not valid");
}

/* If URL is not valid set $website to empty */
if (!preg_match("/^(https?:\/\/+[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/i", $website))
{
    $website = '';
}

/* Let's prepare the message for the e-mail */
$message = "Hello!

Your contact form has been submitted by:

Name: $yourname
E-mail: $email
URL: $website

Comments:
$comments

End of message
";

/* Send the message using mail() function */
mail($myemail, $subject, $message);

/* Redirect visitor to the thank you page */
header('Location: thanks.htm');
exit();

/* Functions we used */
function check_input($data, $problem='')
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
    {
        show_error($problem);
    }
    return $data;
}

function show_error($myError)
{
?>

<html>
    <body>
        <b>Please correct the following error:</b><br />
        <?php echo $myError; ?>
    </body>
</html>

<?php
exit();
}
?>
```

I can post the CSS if I need to. Has anyone ever heard of a mail form doing this?

Here are the links to the pages if it helps.

This is the bare bones page that the form works fine on: 
[Working test page](http://www.the-ecclesia.org/phpmailtest.html)

This is my contact page that I'm trying to get it to work on and it won't:
[non-working actual page](http://www.the-ecclesia.org/contactus.html)

At this point I'd appreciate any info as I've been banging against this wall since Thursday night and my head hurts...LOL

Answer (score 3):

You need to clear the floats from your containers...

```
.container {
  width: 980px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  clear: both;
}
```

Modern browsers have incorporated tools that allow you to inspect what is going on with the HTML and CSS. In Chrome it's View > Developer > Developer Tools. Firebug is a nice plugin for Firefox and Opera has Dragonfly. With these tools it takes 3 seconds to find the problem (your bottom container was obstructing the form), with this information it's easier to solve any rendering problems.

Comment: Well, that was just stupidly simple! LOL! Thank you Duopixel, I've looked at that page till it was all running together. Even used the dev tools last night but just didn't see it..forest/trees/too much coffee...who knows. Again..thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

Adding `display: inline-block;` to the `<div class="container">` makes it editable. So I believe you could say it was uneditable due to CSS... Really don't know why, though.